# I am unable to download the pdf file from url using File transfer in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FileTransfer,  FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';

constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File, private router: Router) { }

  download(){
      const url = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf';

      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      console.log("************")
      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalDataDirectory + 'file.pdf', true).then((entry) => {
        console.log(this.file.externalDataDirectory);
        console.log("entry",entry)
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      }, (error) => {
        // handle error
         console.log("fghnjj");
      });      
  }
```

could you please help me with this?

Comment: do you get an error? this is in android?

Comment: yes. i got this error in android.. unable to download file in android device

Comment: are you targeting sdk 30? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/480 also see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/426#issuecomment-756757287

Comment: @SurajRao where i have to add these permission in my project       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: something like `<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>` in platform android section of config.xml. You may need to re add platform....

Comment: thank you for your time and concern. I have implemented in the same way as you suggested , but still iam facing the issue to download the file.

Comment: What does the error say? There is not much info to help you